# How to mark an Account based on a product that was sold in an opportunity?

Tags: roll-up-summary

I need to mark a field on account (can be roll-up), based on if an item exists or not in any of it's closed-won opportunities.

- I want to have that for all historical data as well (I can use a WFR, but that will only update new/updated opptys)

  - Rollup summary can not work, neither from account, nor from oppty (can't iterate the product line items)
  - Simple formula - again, can't iterate, nor does it see lineitems.

  ** I can't filter the roll up by name.
- I looked at Andrew's https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries - This does not give me access from account to line-item

The first tackle will be to mark the Oppty based on the product (from there I can do the Account-Oppty rollup.

But how do I do that? (not using WFR)

---- Available fields for filter on the roll up
[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "can't iterate the product line items". You could just create a roll up summary on Opportunity of Opportunity Products, which is what you need, right?

Comment: yes, only that I can't filter by the product name, "aggregatable" fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries by Andrew.

Since the 'Name' field is not visible on the productlineitem (yea, weird) I used the 'ProductCode'

Gave the products a unique code, and the declarative rule is based on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems too simple (maybe I am missing the OPs requirment) but here it goes:

1. Create a rollup field on Opportunity called `Count_Of_Product__c`
2. This rolls up the count of a specific product (defined in rollup) on the opportunity
3. Add a Roll up on Account say `Count_Of_Product__c` that rolls up the `Opportunity.Count_Of_Product__c`

Done. A Rollup of a rollup

Comment: I can't filter by name of product.

Comment: What about product ID? You could also add a field on OLI to populate a Text field with the Product Name (WFR or PB). Then you could use that to filter....

Comment: not available. see in Q new image

Comment: Then the second part of my comment should work. But it will require a WFR (even a before update trigger) to populate a text field. That field should then be available for a rollup filter on opp

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you consider running a schedulable class to do the work for you. Presumably you could schedule the class to either run from a trigger or run daily (your choice).  See Dan Appleman's DF14 Video [Design Patterns for Asynchronous Apex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqqiIg_mynY&index=61&list=WL) along with the new release of his book [Advanced Apex Programming Ver 3](http://advancedapex.com/). The sample code from the webinar is available at http://advancedapex.com/dreamforce13/. This would allow you to capture your historical data while also maintaining it as new opportunities are closed using the same design pattern without consuming a lot of API calls.

Comment: Thanks, I always try to avoid code. Especially with Builder and visual flow now available.